# cacheing in jsf 2 while opening different browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am editing different row in different browser, I press F5 in first browser before saving it picked up data which is opened in other browser and populate in first. 
How to overcome with this problem,
I and using requestScope

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this probem by using below code above class declaraionion in bean

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean(name = "roundingBean")
@Scope("session")
public class RoundingBean extends UIInput implements NamingContainer,
    Serializable {
....
}
```